How to calculate the integral of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ between $0$ and $1$?
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{x}}dx$$
I followed the calculation process for $\int_{0}^{1}x^{x}dx$, but encountered some issues.
$$
f\left( x \right) =\int_0^1{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}dx=\int_0^1{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{x}\ln x \right) ^n}{n!}}}dx
\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1{\left( \frac{1}{x}\ln x \right) ^ndx}}
$$
Let $u=\ln x\Rightarrow x=e^u$
$du=\frac{1}{x}dx\Rightarrow dx=e^udu$
$u\left( 0 \right) =-\infty$, $  u\left( 1 \right) =0$
$$
g\left( x \right) =\int_0^1{\left( \frac{1}{x}\ln x \right) ^ndx}=\int_{-\infty}^0{\left( \frac{u}{e^u} \right) ^ne^udu}=\int_{-\infty}^0{\frac{u^n}{e^{\left( n-1 \right) u}}du}
\\
$$
$t=\left( n-1 \right) u\Rightarrow u=\frac{t}{n-1}\Rightarrow du=\frac{dt}{n-1}$
$t\left( -\infty \right) =-\infty  t\left( 0 \right) =0$
$$
g\left( x \right) =\int_{-\infty}^0{\frac{1}{e^t}\left( \frac{t}{n-1} \right) ^n\frac{dt}{n-1}}=\frac{1}{\left( n-1 \right) ^{n+1}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}{e^{-t}}t^ndt
$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function
The domain of definition is from 0 to $+\infty$
I can't use it. I also found that when n=1, the denominator is 0.
How to solve this problem correctly?

This approach does not work because $\int_0^{1}\frac {\ln x} x dx=-\infty$.

apart from the fact that your integral equals $\int_0^\infty e^{-u(1+e^u)}du=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-u} W! \left(u \right)^{2}}{u^{2} \left(1+W! \left(u \right)\right)}d u\approx 0.35$ I don't see how to simplify it...

This has been asked before here and here, but no good answer has been found.

At first sight, I would perform a substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$, this would turn your boundaries from $1$ to $+\infty$ and you wouldn't need a fraction in the exponent.

@vanderWolf I used Mathematica to obtain an approximate result of 0.353497.
